# How to find peaks in an image using matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to outline all peaks in an image. The brightest lines are the peaks. I am using Matlab. This is what I have so far.... 
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here is the image.

[image]

```
a = imread('duneLiDARs.png');
%b = imregionalmax(a);
%a = rgb2gray(a);
c = edge(a,'Sobel');
b = edge(a,'log',.0006);
d = edge(a,'log');
c= imfuse(a,d);
d= d-b;

subplot(2,2,1), imshow(a)
subplot(2,2,2), imshow(b)
subplot(2,2,3), imshow(c)
subplot(2,2,4), imshow(d)
%imshow(b);
%c = imadd(a,b);
%imshow(b);
```

Comment: How do you define peak? point with no values around that are brigther?

Answer (score 1):

you need to define what do you consider as peaks - what is the desired output for your image.

however, there are some general 2D peaks finding function, the following code uses [FEX's extrema2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12275-extrema-m--extrema2-m):

```
% load image and remove extreme noise
im = medfilt2(  im2double(imread('dune.png')));
% find peaks using extrema2
[XMAX,IMAX,XMIN,IMIN] = extrema2(im);
% eliminate peaks under minimum threshold
underThresh = XMAX < 0.15;
IMAX(underThresh) = [];
XMAX(underThresh) = [];
% plotting
subplot(121);
surf(im,'EdgeColor','none');
hold on;
[y,x] = ind2sub(size(im),IMAX);
scatter3(x,y,XMAX,'r','filled');
axis square
subplot(122);
imshow(im,[]);
hold on;
scatter(x,y,'r','filled');
```

[image]